# Create a sqlite databse table having foreign key as column of table in android. I am facing following error. How can i solve this

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

The code for table creation :

```
public static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + USER +
        "("
        + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_USER_DISABLES + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" +
        ")";

public static final String CREATE_DEVICE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + DEVICE +
        "("
        + KEY_DEVICE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + KEY_DID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DEVICE_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DEVICE_DISABLES + " TEXT" +
        ")";

public static final String CREATE_USER_DEVICE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + USER_DEVICE + " ("
        + KEY_USER_DEVICE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_USER_DEVICE_DISABLES + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_UD_USER+ " INTEGER NOT NULL , FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_UD_USER+") REFERENCES "+USER+" ("+KEY_USER_ID+"),"
        + KEY_UD_DEVICE+ " INTEGER NOT NULL , FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_UD_DEVICE+") REFERENCES "+DEVICE+" ("+KEY_DEVICE_ID+"));";


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    /* creating user table */
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

    /* creating device table */
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DEVICE_TABLE);

    /* creating user-device table */
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_DEVICE_TABLE);
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "u_id": syntax error (code 1): , 
       while compiling: CREATE TABLE user_device (did INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
       false TEXT, d_id INTEGER NOT NULL , 
       FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES users (id),u_id INTEGER NOT NULL , 
       FOREIGN KEY (u_id) REFERENCES device (id));
```

Comment: is KEY_USER_DEVICE_DISABLES supposed to show as "false" in the generated query ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct sysntax

```
CREATE TABLE user_device (did INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
false TEXT, d_id INTEGER NOT NULL , 
u_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES users (id),
FOREIGN KEY (u_id) REFERENCES device (id));
```

as you can see on
[image]

because *table constraints* go after *column defs*.